# SQL query with WHERE clause acts as if it's using a % wildcard operator

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, where-clause

SQL Server 2008: 
I have a query that uses a `WHERE` clause to find rows with a specific string. So, let's say I'm looking for entries with the string `1234`, the query would resemble...

```
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE [column] LIKE '1234'
```

Although, this query works, it also returns the rows with the string `1234 [A]` and `1234 [B]`.

I'm not sure why it's acting as if I am using the `%` wildcard operator. So, I need something that returns a strict equality. I haven't used Microsoft SQL Server in a while, so I'm wondering if I'm missing something obvious. I looked into `COLLATION` but that only seems to deal with case and accent sensitivity.

Comment: Just use an equality operator, ex. "[column] = '1234'"

Comment: It is normal to use `=` rather than `LIKE` here, but the query you posted should do what you want. There may be a different problem.

Comment: Seconding the notion that there's something else going on with your query. You should use = anyway unless you actually need to use LIKE for pattern matching on certain queries, but the query you've posted should return the results you're expecting.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE [column] = '1234'
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought, but the equals does not solve my problem either.

Comment: @ornjman What do you mean "does not solve my problem"? Are you saying that when you use ` = '1234'` you also get rows where valye is `'1234 [A]'`? If so, either your where clause is commented out, you are seeing results like `'[A]'` in the next column over and assuming they are part of this column, or there is something else going on that you're not telling us. Can you post a full repro instead of just the query?

Comment: Yes, I'm still getting '1234 [A]' when I use the ` = '1234'`.

I just realized that this query was changed to use a JOIN though, but I don't see how that affects it. So, I'm going to have to take a look at the JOIN statement, because I tried it without the join and it works as I would want it to, strictly returning '1234' without the '1234 [A]'. However, when it's used with the JOIN statement I get the extra results. However, I will have to get back in the morning because of an emergency. So, I thank you for all the help.

Does anyone know how a join statement would make it do that?

Comment: Check which columns are actually being used. If you had 2 tables, T1 (id, value), and T2 (id, value), and you did a query like:

select T1.id, T2.value from T1
inner join T2 on T1.id = T2.id
where T1.value = "ABCD"

...you'd end up selecting the rows from T1 where value="ABCD", but your value column would be full of results from T2...which, if they're in the format "ABCD [1]", "ABCD [2]", etc., would give you those results. Check that you're actually looking at the right column.

If that's the reason, you have another problem in that your database probably isn't properly normalized.

Comment: OK, so thanks for all the help. Something else was going on and I figured out that it was sort of looking at the wrong columns. The results "ABCD" and "ABCD [1]" actually contain the same identifier 'ABCD'. It's confusing without a full example, but I have two processes "ABCD" and "ABCD [1]" that both use the part 'ABCD'. Although the process is named the same as the part, it includes other parts. I was expecting only the part back, but the query actually returns the processes rather than the part. Thanks for working through this and it definitely was an awakening to the power of the JOIN!

Answer (score 1):

Just use the equal operator

```
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE [column] = '1234'
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought, but the equals does not solve my problem either.